# Dont undertand how this star system functions

Tags: javascript

I was following along with a video to implement a rating system using HTML, CSS and JavaScript and was able to understand the majority of it. What I was not able to understand, was how the for loop, under the comment `//remove fill from star` is able to remove the filling from each star and restore it its default state.

```
// Rating Javascript
const stars = document.querySelector(".material-icons-rating-stars").children;

//There are 10 stars

for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
  stars[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    // Remove fill from star
    for (let y = 0; y < stars.length; y++) {
      stars[y].innerHTML = "";
      stars[y].innerHTML = "star_border";
    };

    // Fill each individual star
    for (let x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
      stars[x].innerHTML = '';
      stars[x].innerHTML = "star";
    };
  });
};
```

Link to the full video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-k7gHpYszg

*Note I made a few changes specific for my application.
I am using stars from google icon which allow me to use words to display the image. star shows a filled star, while star_border shows an unfilled star with a border around it. The html is below.

```
<section class="material-icons-rating-stars">
    <i class="material-icons google_star">star_border</i>
    ...
</section>
```

Comment: You should perhaps link the video too.

Comment: Can't say much without looking at the full code, but it seems like `stars[y].innerHTML = "";` . In this "" means empty string. So at each index `y` it is replacing the contents with an empty string, i.e ""

Comment: These empty string assignments seem entirely superfluous though, since a new value is immediately assigned in the next line.

Comment: @JGFMK I've updated with video link and the html

Comment: @mishsx, i've updated the question with the html and more infomation on how it works

Comment: @CherryDT, I didnt know that, I thought it appended to the existing string. Thank you

Comment: `+=` instead of `=` would append.

Comment: @mishsx. Thank you you explination allowed me to figure it out.